# esx five m inventory string issue

Tags: esx

[enter image description here]([https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk8V7.[enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk8V7.%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqnZu.png)pn[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rc3Y.png)g)

Please can some one help,  i have attached 3 images of all code need for this issue

getting bad argument #1 to 'upper' (string expected, got nil) i have posted code below as well:

mf/src/client

```
local internalOpenWeaponLoadout = function(data)
  local k,v = ESX.GetWeapon(data.name)

  local categories = {}

  local weapon = {
    name = data.name:lower(),
    label = data.label,
    WeaponId = data.metadata.WeaponUniqueId,
    components = {}
  }
```

esx/commom/functions

```
function ESX.GetWeapon(weaponName)
    weaponName = string.upper(weaponName)

    for k,v in ipairs(Config.Weapons) do
        if v.name == weaponName then
            return k, v
        end
     end
end
```

I tried changing string to match weaponname 'lower'